# Image from Rich Text Field is not visible in community site to guests

Tags: permissions, force.com-sites

We are using Rich Text fields to allow our users to upload images that are displayed in our community site.  This has been working or us for years.  Guest users, logged in users they can all see the images no problem in our current community sites, in both sandbox and in production.

Now we are developing a new community site now and we are trying to use the same fields and now all of the sudden we are having a problem where the guest users cannot view the images from the Rich Text fields.

Logged in users can see them no problem.  I have checked the field access, and it is the same as the existing sites that are working, and the ablity to get the field text does not seem to be a problem just the server refuses to serve them the actual image.  The image urls in question look something like this:

https://domain-redacted.cs42.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=01t36000003M1od&feoid=00N3600000SEVfR&refid=0EM36000001JxdY

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000330220&type=1

Comment: I have seen that page, and I know it says it is not supposed to work, but it does in this case.  I think maybe this has something to do with how the servlet is hosted as an endpoint from a community site.  The community site assigns a guest user profile to unauthenticated users so it is able to gain some permissions that way.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has this similar issue.  The problem was related to Summer Release 22, which was applied on the sandbox that was having the problems and not the other sites.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000364131&type=1

This update requires you to explictly set up sharing rules if you want guest users to be able to access product records, and product records are where we have the rich text field.

We had access to the markup for the field becasue we were pulling it using apex code running on the server, but the user downloads the actual image and they did not have permission due to the changes in the update.  Once I created the sharing rule everything worked as before.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for reference to those who come googling:
steps to upload an image on a public community site:

1. Go to Files
2. Upload a new file with the image desired.
3. Open the image, at the top there is a link called: public link
4. Create the public link if there isn’t yet
5. Click create
6. Copy the link
7. Open it in a new browser tab
8. Right click, “Copy image”
9. Go to the Rich text field, paste the image in the rich text field .
10. Save it. Image should be available for login and guest users